# How to create and run custom tasks in Telligent 5.5

Tags: telligent

Does anyone know any resources regarding to the creation of a custom scheduled task under Telligent 5.5 ?

From what I read, all I need to do is the following:

1.Create a type that implements the ITask2 interface

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Telligent.Tasks;

namespace Project.ScheduledTasks
{
    public class ReminderTask:ITask2
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            string task = "Please hit the breakpoint here";
        }

        public void Load(System.Xml.XmlNode node)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

2.Add the task description in the communityserver.config

```
  <Thread minutes="1">
    <task name="ReminderTask" type="Project.ScheduledTasks.ReminderTask, Project.ScheduledTasks" enabled="true" enableShutDown="false"></task>
  </Thread>
```

Do I need to do anything else ?

Please help :).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is all that you should need to do. Are you having issues?